# ReactJs make a separate file for fetch

Tags: reactjs, function, file, export, fetch

Some days ago, I did a question about Laravel, but now I will make a shot with Nodejs and React.
The main goal is:

- left bar with 4 selects,

  - Depends on first select, the second will show some info.
  - table with info from selects.
- On the right/center,

  - Show the google maps api.
- At the bottom right/center.

  - Panel with tabs. (info from the individual object from the table).

For this, I want to create a file with fetch functions, for later use.
Is there a way to setup a fetch function in a file and reuse it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetch_function } from './fetch_file';

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Items: [],
        is_loaded: false,
    }
    url = "http://localhost:4000";
    this.fetch_function(url, this.state, "Items");
}

componentDidMount() {
}

render() {
    var { is_loaded, Items} = this.state;

    const options_select_items = Items.map((Item, id) => {
        return ({ value: Item.id, label: Item.Name })
    })

    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalClientes">
                <Form.Label column sm={3}>
                    Cliente
                </Form.Label>
                <Col sm={9}>
                    <Select
                        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                        defaultValue={[system_default[0]]}
                        isMulti
                        options={options_select_items}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form>

    );
}
}
export default App;
```

And this is the fetch_file

```
const fetch_function = (url, setState, param) => {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error("Network failure")
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setState({
                [param]: data
            })
        })
        ;
}

module.exports.fetch_function = fetch_function ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible and highly advisable, especially if your project grows.

I suggest using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), since it automatically returns JSON and is easier to use than the fetch API.

I also don't suggest to mutate the state in that file, since it will become a nightmare when maintaining and debugging the code.

Create a `fetch.js` (or whatever you wanna call it)

```
import axios from 'axios';
const apiBaseURL = 'www.whatever.com'

export const GET = url => {
    return axios.get(`${apiBaseURL}/${url}`);
}

// if need for headers etc.

const headers = 'some headers';

export const POST = (url, data) => {
    return axios(`${apiBaseURL}/${url}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        data,
    });
}
```

In the react component:

import the file at the top:

```
import { GET, POST } from './fetch.js';
```

In component method:

```
async getData(apiEndpoint) {
    const { data: Items } = await GET(apiEndpoint);
    if (Items) {
      // Set data to state
      this.setState({ Items });
    }
    else {
      // error
    }
}
```

The same can be achieved with the plain fetch API as well.

Comment: Uh~~~, thank you so much. I started to like NodeJs and React. Because Laravel is a Nightmare.
Sorry for some basic questions, but I am a beginner with Node and React. When you say, "In the react componet and in the component method" Those, will be on the App.js file? Like my first code.